# Cannot integrate PID in my Quadcopter? Is this the right way?

Tags: arduino, pid-controller

I am working in my quadcopter. Right now I am just testing for take- off and Roll angle. I tried to integrate PID library in my code but it keeps generating 100 and my quadcopter goes blasting. Right now I am just giving 1,1,1 for kp,ki and kd. I know this is not right but like I said, I am just playing. Here is my Code. ..

```
    #define CHNL_HIGH 1900
      #define CHNL_LOW 1100

      #define THROTTLE_CHNL 2
      #define CW1_IN 9
      #define CW2_IN 10
      #define CW3_IN 11
      #define CW4_IN 12
      #define ARM_DEG 21
      #define THROTTLE_FLAG 1
      Servo servoCW1;
      Servo servoCW2;
      Servo servoCW3;
      Servo servoCW4;

      int servoCW1_DEG = 0;
      int servoCW2_DEG = 0;
      volatile uint8_t bUpdateFlagsShared;
      volatile uint16_t unThrottleInShared;
      volatile int throttleOffset; 
      uint32_t ulThrottleStart;

      float ypr[3]; // yaw pitch roll

      //Define Variables we'll be connecting to
      double Input_roll,rollOffset,Setpoint_roll;


      PID myPID(&Input_roll, &rollOffset, &Setpoint_roll,1,1,1, DIRECT);

      // Set the FreeIMU object
      FreeIMU my3IMU = FreeIMU();

      void setup() { 
        Serial.begin(115200);
        Wire.begin();

        delay(5);
        my3IMU.init(); // the parameter enable or disable fast mode

         //initialize the variables we're linked to

        Setpoint_roll = -5.00;

        //turn the PID on
        myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
        myPID.SetOutputLimits(-100.00, 100.00);

        servoCW1.attach(CW1_IN);
        servoCW2.attach(CW2_IN); 

        servoCW3.attach(CW3_IN);
        servoCW4.attach(CW4_IN);

        Serial.println("GET IT");
        arm();
        attachInterrupt(0, calcThrottle,CHANGE);


        delay(5);
      }


      void loop()
      {

        static uint16_t unThrottleIn;
        static uint8_t bUpdateFlags;

        // check shared update flags to see if any channels have a new signal
        if(bUpdateFlagsShared)
        {
          noInterrupts(); 

          bUpdateFlags = bUpdateFlagsShared;

          if(bUpdateFlags & THROTTLE_FLAG)
          {
            unThrottleIn = unThrottleInShared;
          }

          bUpdateFlagsShared = 0;

          interrupts(); // we have local copies of the inputs, so now we can turn interrupts back on

        }

       if(bUpdateFlags & THROTTLE_FLAG)

       {
            throttleChange(unThrottleIn);


       }
        my3IMU.getYawPitchRoll(ypr);
        Input_roll = ypr[2];
        myPID.Compute();
        rollChange(rollOffset);
        bUpdateFlags = 0;
      }



      void rollChange(double rollOffset)
      {
        int valCW1 = servoCW1.readMicroseconds();
        int valCW2 =  servoCW2.readMicroseconds();
      Serial.print("offset:       ");
        Serial.println(rollOffset);
        valCW1 = valCW1 + rollOffset;
        valCW2 = valCW2 - rollOffset;
       Serial.print("valCW1:       ");
        Serial.println(valCW1);

        Serial.print("valCW2:      ");
        Serial.println(valCW2);
         Serial.println("");
          Serial.println("");

        servoCW1.writeMicroseconds((int)valCW1);
        servoCW2.writeMicroseconds((int)valCW2);
      }
      void arm()
      {

        servoCW1.write(ARM_DEG);
        servoCW2.write(ARM_DEG);

        servoCW3.write(ARM_DEG);
        servoCW4.write(ARM_DEG);

      }

      void throttleChange(int cha_val)
      {


          servoCW1.writeMicroseconds(cha_val);
          servoCW2.writeMicroseconds(cha_val);

          servoCW3.writeMicroseconds(cha_val);
          servoCW4.writeMicroseconds(cha_val);

      }

      void calcThrottle()
      {
        if(digitalRead(THROTTLE_CHNL) == HIGH)
        {
          ulThrottleStart = micros();
        }else
        {

          unThrottleInShared = (uint16_t)(micros() - ulThrottleStart);
          bUpdateFlagsShared |= THROTTLE_FLAG;
        }
      }
```

I am getting an rollOffset from the PID controller. And action is taken in the rollchange() function. My setpoint is -5.00.

Problem:
The PID outputs 100 most of the time. And, I don't think it is helping to reach my setpoint but it is really destroying it. So my question is am I really using the output from PID the right way.

Comment: Tried inverting the PID output? -rollOffset

Comment: Not sure what you asked... But I am adding to one motor and subracting to other... Since i am expecting [ -100, 100] as rollOffset.. Did i answer it right?? Sorrry im a noob

Comment: Sorry, typed that one while eating. I think I see the error. You are subtracting and adding the PID output to your current value of valCWX. This way you are effectively integrating the PID output. This makes the Proportional term into _Integral_, Differential into _Proportional_ and Integral into _2nd order Integral_. Most certainly you don't want that.

Comment: hmmmmm Ok.. So what do you suggest I do with the output to reach the desired set point......

Answer (score 2):

PID's output is *generally* designed to be plugged *directly* into output as your control variable. That means without any subtractions of additions. I am getting the impression that your code would require some major corrections. As a quick bodge fix you could, however, try it like this:

> ```
> valCW1 =  rollOffset;
> valCW2 = - rollOffset;
> ```
>
> WRONG: The overall output has to be positive.

You need not just one PID, but more. One for roll, one for yaw, one for pitch, one for altitude. After you get all the PID outputs, you *add them together*, and plug that directly into your valCWX variables. Perhaps something in this manner (renamed *offset* to *result*):

```
valCW1 = altitudeResult + rollResult + yawResult;
valCW2 = altitudeResult - rollResult + yawResult;
valCW3 = altitudeResult + pitchResult - yawResult;
valCW4 = altitudeResult - pitchesult - yawResult;
```

With this, and some luck, you should be able to control the thing entirely. But one more thing comes to mind. Value clamping.

I suspect Arduino already has a function *constrain(x, min, max)*. Apply this to your outputs.

Comment: Can you write a -ve value to the writeMicroSecond() ??. I had an impression that you can only change roll if there is a difference in speed of CW motors. BUt there is only 1 output. So i thought why no subtr and add to change the two speed..

Comment: what is the altitudeResult PID? What would the input be for this PID? And, You can see I am directly writing the radio controls signal to the motor and then doing the PID.... Do you see any problem with that? Again My PID output limit is set to [-100,100] anything you have to say about that? Would it be the same for all the PID's you mentioned

Comment: Perhaps I am not seeing it correctly, but it seems to me that you are getting the _servoCWX.readMicroseconds_ value, adjusting it, and then writing it back to the servo.

Comment: And the altitudeResult is just _something_ that adds a significant positive offset from zero, so that other values can add and subtract from it. It can as well be called _throttle_ or _myPositiveOffset_